# RD Connection via RDGW to Session host is not connecting

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2016, rds, session, remote-desktop-gateway

I'm building a new RDS solution with a Gateway/Connection Broker and a pair of session host servers etc.

This isn't the first time I've done this and I've not hit this issue before; I'm hoping its something stupid, but I'm scratching my head and I've been unable to resolve with hours of troubleshooting.

So I've finished the deployment and am testing.
I've added the Desktop collection via RemoteApp and Desktop connections.
I tell it to connect and I'm prompted for a username and password. 
I enter them and it looks like its going to go through, then it either hangs on "configuring remote session" and goes nowhere, or sometimes after a minute or so It errors and says It cant connect and to please try again later.

I've been scouring through the logs on the Gateway and I can see things seem to start off ok but then I see disconnects but no explanation...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hope you find the culprit, I have a Setup with this exact problem. Not all Session hosts at the same time, but today one and tomorrow another. After reboot everything is fine again.